# How can I transfer UISlider value on SecondViewController to Alarm on FirstViewController?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have two ViewControllers, FirstViewController and SecondViewController.
And there is UISlider on SecondViewController. There is an alarm on FirstViewController.

Now I want to transfer UISlider value, which is volume to alarm on FirstViewController.

ps. The function what I want to make is totally same as default iPhone setting slider.

I would be so happy so if you guys give me your knowledge, please.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, 
UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

let TODO = ["A", "B", "C"]

let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
var volume = Float()
var counter = 0
var timer = Timer()
var startTime:Double = 0.0
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func firstSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch)
{
    if (sender).isOn
    {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1 * 1, repeats: false, block: { timer in


            self.audioPlayer.play()

            self.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
            print(self.audioPlayer.isPlaying)
        })
    }else{
        timer.invalidate()
        print("switch1stopped")
        self.audioPlayer.stop()
    }
}

    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(catchNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "test"), object: nil)

}

@objc func catchNotification(notification: Notification) -> Void {
    print("Catch notification")
    audioPlayer.volume = volumeChane.value
    //Use of unresolved identifier 'volumeChane'
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
@IBOutlet weak var volumeSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var volumeLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func volumeChange(_ sender: UISlider)
{
    volumeLabel.text = String(Int(sender.value))
    volumeSlider.value = sender.value
    audioPlayer.volume = volumeSlider.value
    notificationCenter.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "test"), object: nil)

    audioPlayer.play()
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let url=Bundle.main.url(forResource:"Alarm",withExtension:".mp3" )
    {

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
            audioPlayer?.play(atTime:1 * 10)

        }catch{
            audioPlayer = nil
        }
    }else{
        fatalError("Url is nil")
    }

}
extension Notification.Name
{
   static let myNotificationName = Notification.Name("test")
}
```

Comment: You can use delegates

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I use that? sorry I am a beginner so I would like more specific answer...

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSNotificationCenter` for a simple task such as this might be an overkill. You usually use closures to catch data changes in your components or view controllers.

In the `SecondViewController` create a variable containing a closure:

`var onVolumeChange: ((value: Float) -> Void)?`

Call it in the `IBAction` that monitors slider's onChange event.

```
@IBAction func volumeChange(_ sender: UISlider)
{
    self.onVolumeChange?(sender.value)
}
```

Pass the `onVolumeChange` closure from the `FirstViewController` when navigating to the second one. I'm not sure how you perform navigation so I'll assume you do it programmatically.

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
vc.onVolumeChange = { value in 
    audioPlayer.volume = value
}
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```